# Paypal API Phonegap - Recurring payments with Phonegap IOS HTML5 App

Tags: jquery, cordova, paypal

I'm trying to implement a shop into a IOS HTML5 Phonegap app which runs off a .aspx CMS (via xml feeds).

I need to implement client payments - both individual one off payments and recurring payments for repeat services

I have used Paypal in the past to do something similar with individual payments - (simply using their provided form and altering the description and cost fields accordingly in the CMS) - but I cant seem to get it working via Phonegap as i just receive whitelist errors and it wont trigger the form.

I have looked through the Paypal API docs and it isn't really clear whether this should work in a HTML5 app - does anyone have any experience with implementing recurring payments for Phonegap?  I also wondered whether it was possible to get flags / emails when a recurring payment is cancelled so we can react to this server side?

Any other suggestions for suitable payment API's also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of recurring billing solutions out there, and most come with a JSON or XML API that you could work easily with:

**Chargify >** http://chargify.com/

**Recurly >** http://recurly.com/

**Spreedly >** http://spreedly.com/

To name just a few...

Comment: Cheers Ben - my main problem is getting them to work in Phonegap - it whitelist errors when using phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal or any other web service would work just fine in PhoneGap.  I've used it plenty within Titanium Appcelerator, jQuery Mobile, and Sencha.

You can hit PayPal's API directly using NVP, XML, or JSON, or what I typically do is build my own PHP web services so that I can also handle my own database updates, 3rd party web service calls, email notifications, social network updates, etc. all from within those services and simplify everything from within the mobile app itself.